# Searching a dataframe to see if a substring exists in another dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, substring

I'm having trouble to find a solution to this issue where I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2.

```
df1
    C1      C2
0   apple   5
1   grape   11
2   orange  7
3   cherry  9

df2
    Item
0   apple soda
1   cherry cola
2   grape juice
3   apple candy
4   bubblegum apple
5   orange citrus
6   funky grapefruit
7   sweet banana
```

How do I search the strings in df2 and check if a substring exists in df1 which then returns the value from df1 into a new column in df2?

Here's the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
df2
    Item                C2
0   apple soda          5
1   cherry cola         9
2   grape juice         11
3   apple candy         5
4   bubblegum apple     5     
5   orange citrus       7  
6   funky grapefruit    11     
7   sweet banana        Null
```

Comment: What happens if you have several matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'C1': ['apple', 'grape', 'orange', 'cherry'],
         'C2': [5, 11, 7, 9]}

data2 = {'Item': ['apple soda', 'cherry cola', 'grape juice', 'apple candy',
                  'bubblegum apple', 'orange citrus', 'funky grapefruit', 'sweet banana']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

def find_matching_value(row):
    matching_rows = df1[df1['C1'].apply(lambda x: x in row['Item'])]
    if not matching_rows.empty:
        return matching_rows['C2'].iloc[0]
    return None

df2['C2'] = df2.apply(find_matching_value, axis=1)

print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
          Item    C2
0        apple soda   5.0
1       cherry cola   9.0
2       grape juice  11.0
3       apple candy   5.0
4   bubblegum apple   5.0
5     orange citrus   7.0
6  funky grapefruit  11.0
7      sweet banana   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a regex, [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) (or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)):

```
import re

pattern = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['C1']))
# '(apple|grape|orange|cherry)'

df2['C2'] = (df2['Item'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
             .map(df1.set_index('C1')['C2'])
            )
```

Output:

```
               Item    C2
0        apple soda   5.0
1       cherry cola   9.0
2       grape juice  11.0
3       apple candy   5.0
4   bubblegum apple   5.0
5     orange citrus   7.0
6  funky grapefruit  11.0
7      sweet banana   NaN
```

Alternative with `merge`:

```
out = df2.merge(df1, left_on=df2['Item'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False),
                right_on='C1', how='left')
```

Output:

```
               Item      C1    C2
0        apple soda   apple   5.0
1       cherry cola  cherry   9.0
2       grape juice   grape  11.0
3       apple candy   apple   5.0
4   bubblegum apple   apple   5.0
5     orange citrus  orange   7.0
6  funky grapefruit   grape  11.0
7      sweet banana     NaN   NaN
```

##### several matches

If you have several matches, the abode solution will only map the **first** match. If you want to perform an operation on all, you can use this variant (here to get the sum):

```
df2['C2_sum'] = (df2['Item'].str.extractall(pattern)[0].droplevel(1)
                  .map(df1.set_index('C1')['C2']).groupby(level=0).sum()
                 )
```

Output:

```
                Item  C2_sum
0  apple cherry soda    14.0  # 5+9
1        cherry cola     9.0
2        grape juice    11.0
3        apple candy     5.0
4    bubblegum apple     5.0
5      orange citrus     7.0
6   funky grapefruit    11.0
7       sweet banana     NaN
```